# Как задать SearchView в коде?

Tags: android, actionbar, android-search-view

Есть одна `Activity` с множеством `Fragment`, но требуемый `SearchView` должен появляться только на определенных `Fragment` в `ActionBar` со своей логикой.

Но возникает проблема не ясная мне - код одного из `Fragment`:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "create menu in fragmnt ");

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.add("Search");
        searchItem.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
        searchItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

        SearchView sv = new SearchView(getActivity());
        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "TextSubmit " + query);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "TextChange " + newText);
                return true;
            }
        });

//        searchItem.setActionView(sv);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

Если оставить как есть то отображается иконка, если расскомменитровать `searchItem.setActionView(sv);` то иконка перестает отображаться.

Как правильно задать создание `SearchView` в коде фрагмента?

Comment: по идее смысла создавать програмно нет, у MenuItem есть метод на установку видимости setVisible(), достаточно лишь делать проверку на соответствие нужного фрагмента и затем прятать/показывать ваш menuItem

Comment: @АндроидАндроид то есть например в Activity в методе onPrepareOptionsMenu, определить соотвествие нужному фрагменту? Подскажите как сделать это лаконично, в голову приходят только подобный метод getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame).getClass().getName(), где content_frame - контейнер для фрагментов.

Comment: можно проверять с помощью if (ThisFragment instanceof MyFragment) типа такого

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Благодарю, ваш совет мне помог и подошел